# Как параллельное изменение базы данных сделать последовательным?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Разрабатываю проект с использованием WebAPI и Entity Framework 6.

Есть контроллер с методом, который добавляет новую сущность Task в БД. У Task перед добавление рассчитывается уникальное имя. Часть имени создается на основе уже сохраненных Task в БД. Если сделать два параллельных запроса, то можно сгенерировать одинаковые имена, эта проблема решена через lock.

Как не допустить генерацию одинаковых имен, если будет запущенно два сервера WebAPI c подключением к одной БД?

Можно ли добавить алгоритм добавления Task в последовательную очередь на уровне БД?

Упрощенный код:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/tasks")]
public class TaskController1 : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("add")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddTask()
    {
        using (var db = CreateDbContext())
        {
            Task task = new Task();

            lock (lockAdd)
            {
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

                string preName = dateTime.ToString("yyMMdd-HHmm-");

                var query = db.Tasks.Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith(preName)).Select(t => t.Name);

                List<string> tasksNames = query.ToList();

                task.Name = preName + (tasksNames.Count + 1).ToString("D4");

                db.Tasks.Add(task);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему бы не генерировать это имя в самой БД?

Comment: @tym32167 Как его нужно генерировать в БД, чтобы избежать дублирования имени?

Comment: У вас очень странный алгоритм. Я правильно понимаю, что `tasksNames.Count` это количество задач с названиями в одну дату. Но тогда если вы добавили в в БД 3 записи и потом первую удалили, то ваш алгоритм даст Count=2, что приведет к созданию имени дата-3, но запись 3 то уже есть ...

Comment: @Mike Алгоритм упрощен, можно считать, что Task никогда не удаляется и такой проблемы не возникнет.

Comment: Если бы вы смогли изобразить получение количества в виде `select count(1) from (select * from Task where name like 'дата%' for update) X` то все записи с указанной датой были бы заблокированы и другой процесс в БД бы ждал завершения вашей транзакции. Правда остается проблема с первой записью, когда блокировать еще не чего ...

Comment: Кстати, а наличие даты в имени и именно количества записей в эту дату принципиально ?

Comment: @Mike, принципиально.

Comment: Предлагаю использовать костыль. Отдельную табличку(или хранимую процедуру), в которой генерируются ID для таски. Делаете это до сохранения, база обеспечивает уникальность.

Comment: Предлагаю другой костыль. Делаете отдельную табличку, в которую никогда ничего не пишите. Перед началом операции выдачи номера, начинаете транзакцию, берете на эту табличку эксклюзивную блокировку, считаете записи, добавляете задачу, фиксируете транзакцию. т.е. фактически эта таблица будет чем то вроде вашей переменной lockAdd, только на уровне БД

Comment: При желании можно завести в БД процедуру getTaskName в которой проделывать всю эту работу, главное из C# вызывать эту процедуру в пределах той же транзакции, которая добавляет задачу

Answer (score 0):

Для генерации уникального имени внутри базы вы можете воспользоваться системной хранимой процедурой **NEWID()**.

Для обеспечения уникальности по вашему алгоритму необходимо сделать колонку уникальной, а саму вставку производить в рамках транзакции. При такой реализации вы можете столкнуться с OptimisticConcurrencyException. Как это можно решить [рассказано в англоязычной статье](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Такой вариант рассматривался. Проблема в том, что колонку нельзя сделать уникальной. Т.к. имена могут совпадать, но конкретно в этом методе они должны создаваться уникальными.

Comment: Нет ли возможности сделать ограничение по нескольким столбцам. К примеру, ограничение будет включать колонки имя и метку времени (строковое представление, до секунд). В случае если имя и метка времени совпадёт запись не вставится.